# Why does the manifest file play a crucial role sometimes?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, manifest

I tried compiling the code keeping the **linker->manifest file->generate manifest file= Yes** on visual2015 the code didn't work for 64bit windows 10 but it worked fine for 32 bit.

Then I changed property as **linker->manifest file->generate manifest file= No**
now code is working fine for both **32 and 64 bit**.

So my question what happens when I do the above change in property?
How the `manifest file` plays its role at runtime?

I have tried to google but couldn't get it thoroughly so help me with this.

Comment: A manifest is **required** for all Windows versions for the past 10 years.  It contains configuration information beyond what can be done with the PE executable file format.  Most crucially it declares the program compatible with UAC, without the manifest the OS treats your program like a legacy program and you'll have wonky problems with files and registry keys.  A C++ project always has a bitness dependency, just a small corner case for a pure MSIL program created by C++/CLI (/clr:pure).  "didn't work" does not help us help you.

Comment: didn't work means I get error saying "Microsoft Management Console has stopped working."

Comment: Ugh, an MMC plugin requires a DLL, not an EXE.  The manifest only matters to an EXE.  Use the debugger to find out why it failed, Project > Properties > Debugging > Command = "mmc.exe".

Comment: In WinDbg I dont get any error when MMC stops. It just crashes without giving any error in WinDbg.